# How can I join 2 different tables with no matching column

Tags: mysql

Example I have table 1:

```
ID   USER   Password
1   name1     pass1
2   name2     pass2
```

Table 2 is blank but have columns:

```
ListID   FNAME    LNAME
null      null    null
null      null    null
```

I want to pass the record from table1 to table 2 or join them together so every record inserted to table 1 will be inserted to table 2 as well.

Comment: Your request doesn't make sense.  What do you want `table2` to look like afterwards.

Comment: Table 1 comes from worksheet so it will be uploaded from our system and our system has it own id that we cannot edit because it's in the system already so what we want to achieve is the uploaded worksheet will be added to the database of our system but my problem is they  have a different columns. i will just add script to system to join it together however we cannot edit the database column name.

Comment: I think you want to add 2 columns into table 2, and copy the values from table 1 to able 2. You are not actually wanting to JOIN them, which is a very different operation.

Answer (score 0):

how about adding an relational id's in both table and truncate it..

Comment: unfortunately we cannot do that since table1 comes from our client already and table 2 is generated already by the system so they have different columns but we can add a script to this system but changing or adding more column to it's database will affect the system's behavior.